# How to set #value to the form item from HTML data-*?

Tags: forms, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

In product.tpl.php I have a code like this:

```
<div class="paint-order" data-pid="<?php print $node->field_product_ref['und'][0]['product_id']; ?>">
```

With JQuery I can get this product_id with this code:

```
var paint_id = new Number($('.paint-order').data('pid'));
```

I create ctools popup form, and want to fill #value of form element

```
$form = array();
$form['form_wrapper']['buy_art_buy_one_click_product_id'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => (string) htmlspecialchars(insert ['product_id'] here),
);
```

What I must to use instead of 'insert ['product_id'] here' to get value of data (or other) HTML-attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this task with `Drupal.behaviors` in js-file

like that:

```
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        var paint_id = new Number($('.paint-order').data('pid'));
        $(context).find("[name='mymodule_product_id']").val(paint_id);

    }
}
```